# Replacing elements in a vector after the first found instance

Tags: matlab, vector, indexing

I have a vector that looks something like

```
V= [24, 25, 26, 27…, 48, 49, 50……, 100, 98, 99, 100, 100, 95, 93, 97, 98, 98, 92….]
```

I want all elements after **first 100** to be 100. I want all elements before first 100 to remain as it is. i.e. I don’t want to change 24,25,26,27….48,49,50….100 as 100.  So I can’t say -- “replace all  elements < 100 to 100”.

**I only want to change all elements after first 100 to 100.**

The new vector will look like--

```
V_new= [24, 25, 26, 27,….., 48, 49, 50, ..., 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]
```

How do I write this in MATLAB? Can anyone help?

Comment: If one of the answers has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates that you've found a solution and this is no longer an open question. If your question is not answered, please explain what’s missing.

Answer (score 3):

First copy over the vector `V` to the new variable `V_new`, then use [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to find the first instance of where you find a value of 100.  After, use this index and from the first point after this to the end of the vector, set the values to 100:

```
V_new = V;
ind = find(V == 100, 1, 'first');
V_new(ind+1:end) = 100;
```

Sometimes using `find` is a bit frowned upon.  An alternative I have is to use [`max`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) and use the second output argument so that you can find the very first time there is a case where `V` has an element of 100.  Then you can do the same thing as before:

```
V_new = V;
[~,ind] = max(V == 100);
V_new(ind+1:end) = 100;
```

Comment: Surely using `max` is not preferable to `find` in this case. `find` is frowned upon because it is often used where logical indexing is sufficient and is thus extraneous.

Comment: @Dan I suppose it's not, but it's nice to come up with an alternative.

Comment: @Aditya Consider accepting one of our answers if you no longer need help.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple one-liner:

```
V(cumsum(V==100) > 0) = 100;
```

---

For example consider

```
>V = [ 8 2 6 1 6 3 ]
```

now

```
n = 6;
V(cumsum(V==n) > 0) = n;
```

breaking this down piece by piece

```
V==n
```

results in a logical matrix that finds any elements of `V` that equal `n` i.e.:

```
0 0 1 0 1 0
```

we then find the cumulative sum i.e. `cumsum(V==n)`:

```
0 0 1 1 2 2
```

Finally we look where this sum is larger than `1`. Not that it will be monotonically increasing and it will always increase by steps of `1` because it was called on a logical matrix. So `cumsum(V==n) > 0`:

```
0 0 1 1 1 1
```

And those are the elements you want to change to just use this as a logical index to `V` so `V(cumsum(V==n)>0)` is the same as `V([0 0 1 1 1 1])`

Comment: This answer could benefit from an explanation. As posted, it is helpful to only those that already know the answer.

Comment: @IInspectable I don't agree with you but I've added the explanation regardless. In MATLAB, it is fairly trivial for someone, even if they don't already know the answer, to just type each section of a line of code out on the command line and see immediately what it results in.